# NHibernate - Map multiple database columns to one object

Tags: nhibernate

I have a database (which cannot be changed) with a whole load of values that are stored in two columns:

Currently each column is mapped to one property and my Domain object looks like this:

```
int? Value1
bool IsValue1RealValue

string Value2
bool IsValue2RealValue

bool? Value3
bool IsValue3RealValue
```

I want to put those into a ValueType which would hold 2 or 3 values:

-The value (stored in `object` or in `T`)
 -The boolean 'RealValue'
 -And (optionally) the name of the .NET property name

At the moment I have the following NHibernate mapping:

```
  Component(x => x.Value1, fdf =>
  {
     fdf.Map(f => f.Value).Column("Value1");
     fdf.Map(f => f.IsRealValue).Column("IsValue1RealValue");
  });
```

`Value1` has the following type:

```
public class FlaggedNullableIntValue
{
    public int? Value;
    public bool IsRealValue;
}
```

My domain object would then look like:

```
public class DomainEntity
{
    public virtual FlaggedNullableIntValue Value1;
    public virtual FlaggedStringValue Value2;
    public virtual FlaggedNullableBooleanValue Value3;
}
```

I wonder if it is a good idea to go further down this road or is there another construct that might better suit my needs?

Comment: I don't think I understand. How do you want your model to look like? Where there are those `T` or `objects` if the the type of `Value` is `int?`? What property name do you want to map?

Comment: I've updated my question. The model would have 1 property for every Value+IsRealValue combination in the database. The value is currently still int, but ideally, the mapped object would be able to handle ints, bools and strings as Type for Value.

Comment: Are you asking if nHibernate has a feature that converts columns in rows (objects) ? If so, I'm pretty sure it's not possible.  You have to map each pair manually.

Comment: You can only map one DB column to one property, this is a `limitation` of NHibernate (if that is a limitation)

Comment: @Rippo, actually, using components as @Laoujin demonstrated is one way to map multiple columns to one property.  Another way is to define an `ICompositeUserType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on exactly the right track.  One suggestion - you should be able to make your `FlaggedNullable*Value` class generic so that you don't have to create lots of different classes.

```
public class FlaggedNullableValue<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public T? Value;
    public bool IsRealValue;
}
```

It looks like you're using Fluent NHibernate to specify your mappings.  As long as you are consistent in the way you name those column pairs, you should be able to create a convention to ease the burden of mapping all those properties and column names.

Comment: We ended up using the `ICompositeUserType` (as per your comment). It works pretty well so far.